# iPhone library: file is not of required architecture

Tags: iphone, linker-errors

I have searched for hours however I still have no clue what is wrong with my configuration.
My project uses a self-written libray (myLib). This library is compiled to work **only** for **simulator** and it works perfectly there.

What do have to change so it compiles for my **iPhone Device** as well?

This is my current warning:

```
ld: warning: in /.../myLib.a, file is not of required architecture
```

This is my configuration (of myLib.a)

[image]

I found a lot of articles explaining the reason for this error however I could not find a solution:

> The simulator runs on an x86
>   architecture, while the device uses an
>   ARM architecture.

---

What do I have to change to get my library working on my iPhone?

Thanks

---

Edit:

What I did so far:

1. Cleaned both projects
2. Set library to 'Device' (3.1)
3. Built the library
4. Dragged the .a file of my library into my application

Result:

This works in simulator but setting the active sdk to device still raises a `file is not of required architecture` error.

I also tried [mahboudz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86020/mahboudz) ( thanks for your support) [link](http://www.martijnthe.nl/2009/08/building-a-cross-platform-iphone-library-in-xcode/).
It explains howto built the project using a shell script.
However XCode keeps complaining that the library file is of the wrong architecture and the build fails.

This has to be a really stupid beginners mistake.

Comment: What is the configuration of the application?

Comment: The application has the same configuration as the library. (I couldn't find any difference). What additional information do you need?

Comment: when you bring the library in to your new application, what is the source location?

Comment: the libary is only added as a reference.

Comment: You might also consider adding the library *project* to the app project, so that both build together. That might help resolve whatever discrepancy you're running into.

Comment: I want to send only the .a files to my customer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add both .a files,the one built for the device (build/$config-iphoneos)and the one built for the sim (build/$config-iphonesimulator) to the new project. Make sure you name them differently before dropping them in. This is how admob and similar offering ship their static libs.

Comment: If you are so inclined, you can use lipo to merge both files into a universl binary

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile your library for Intel so the Simulator can use it (which I gather you have done already), and then compile it for ARM, so it can run on the iPhone.  Then you have to merge the two libraries.  There are different ways to accomplish that, or make it more automatic.

Here are some links to help you:

http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html
http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/

Comment: "6) Build your new static library for all the SDK targets (such as simulator, iPhone Device, etc.)." Of your first link is my problem. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Your second link is about sth similar but not about static libarys. (Apart of the link to stormyprods blog)

Comment: Under the Project menu, what does your Active SDK say?

Comment: active sdk: `iPhone Device 3.1 (Base SDK)` active architecture: `armv6`

Comment: I don't think I have ever had any problems with this.  I made a new project, selected Cocoa Touch Library and then built for device and simulator.  ARM and i386.  Here is another place to look:  http://www.martijnthe.nl/2009/08/building-a-cross-platform-iphone-library-in-xcode/

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem too. But seems you don't need to drag two `.a` files into the app project to solve this problem. This is what I did:

1. Drag the static library project into app project's framework group
2. "Get Info" for the target in app project
3. Set the direct dependency of static library
4. Make clean all unnecessary builds(for example the simulator build) in the static library project
5. Build in the app project